# Classcastexception: Widget cannot be cast to layout

Tags: android, classcastexception

Though this tends to be very basic question, i cannot solve this issue. I searched the similar kind of issue but none solves my issue.

I created my own class where i created some basic controls and i called this class in my xml as

```
<com.mypackagename.classname
..
..
/>
```

and some views goes inside this. and before this now i would like to add relativelayout as

**activity_main1.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android1:layout_width="match_parent"

    android1:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<com.test.MainLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.test.MainLayout>
</RelativeLayout >
```

and i my main activity i declared as 
**MainActivity:**

```
Myview view;
view = (Myview)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null);
        setContentView(view);
```

where MyView is the class where i have my own controls.

After adding relative layout i tried something like

**MainActivity1.java:**

```
public class MainActivity1 extends FragmentActivity 
{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
         view = (Myview)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null);
            item.addView(view);
    setContentView(item); // facing an error here

.......... rest of the code
}
```

and my layout activity is

```
public class MainLayout1 extends LinearLayout 
{
....

}
```

while running it is throwing classcastexception and the error is

**java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to com.view.layout.MainLayout**

Comment: is the layout posted `actiivty_main1.xml`?

Comment: I know that are the fact things but, have you performed all basic steps like clean the project or close the project and re-open it and all that ?

Comment: I cleaned the project and tries all basic steps but still facing the issue @naranz

Comment: OK, can you show those two files(.xml and .java), to get proper idea about the problem ?

Comment: pls check it now @naranz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view = (Myview)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null);

At this point in your java class, you are getting `MyView` Object in view, but it is actually a layout file instance which returns its parent layout here its a `RelativeLayout`.

Since inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null); returns the object of `RelativeLayout`. Instead of this you have to get instance of your MainLayout1 like(R.id.mainlayout) and then cast it into the `MyView` object like:

```
RelativeLayout item = (View)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main1,null);

view = (Myview) item.findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

item.addView(view);

setContentView(item);
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to RelativeLayout error

Comment: Look, first collect object of View that you are inflating(xml file). and then by using that view(m giving its name like view1) object try findViewById to get the instance of your custom layout(MainLayout). After that you can add that MainLayout object into view1.

Comment: I changed the code lightly and now it is displaying properly. Thanks friend :)